# Opencart category module > display second child

Tags: php, oop, filtering, opencart

I've been trying to achieve to display second child of category in the sidebar category module like this

E.g.: `Toys > boys > RC cars`

Currently have this

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <li class="cat-active">
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <b class="cc"></b>
        <ul class="col-subcat">
            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Which only shows

Toys > boys

I'm not sure how to display the 2nd child ("toys > boys > **RC cars**")
Ty for suggestions

Comment: are you thinking about doing some recursive? each time you go one level deeper, you'll have to throw a new <ul> then a <li> loop

Comment: Check this, same I think http://stackoverflow.com/q/13067567/1301076

Comment: Please, do a proper search (using e.g. Google) before asking here. Your question have already been answered here (and there are lot of tutorials on the internet for achieving the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have to customize 2 files.

1. catalog/controller/module/category.php - 39 line

Find "foreach ($children as $child) {" and put following code below it.

```html
$children_data_2 = array();

$children_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

foreach ($children_2 as $child_2) {
 $filter_data = array(
  'filter_category_id'  => $child_2['category_id'],
  'filter_sub_category' => true
 );

 $children_data_2[] = array(
  'category_id' => $child_2['category_id'],
  'name'        => $child_2['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
  'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_2['category_id'])
 );
}
```

Change

```html
$children_data[] = array(
 'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
 'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
 'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
);
```

To

```html
$children_data[] = array(
 'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
 'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
 'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
 'children'   => $children_data_2 // insert this line
);
```

---

2. catalog/view/theme/[your theme directory]/template/module/category.tpl

```html
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <li class="cat-active">
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <b class="cc"></b>
        <ul class="col-subcat">
            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($child['children']) { ?>
    <b class="cc"></b>
    <ul class="col-subcat">
     <?php foreach ($child['children'] as $child_2) { ?>
     <li>
      <?php if ($child_2['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $child_2['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $child_2['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $child_2['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child_2['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } ?>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```